# Why the set of all boundary points of irrational numbers are real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis

Hello nice mathematicians, thanks for reading my question, I have a question. Why the set of all boundary points of the irrational is the set of real numbers?

## Definitions:

### Boundary of a Set

Let $A$ $\subset$ $\Bbb R$ be a set of real numbers and $x$ $\in$ $\Bbb R$. We say that $x$ is a **boundary point** of $A$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains at lest one point of $A$ and at least one point of $A^C$. The set of all boundary points of $A$ is called the **boundary** of $A$, and is denoted $A^b$.

### $\epsilon$-Neighborhood

Let $x$ $\in$ $\Bbb R$ and $\epsilon$>$0$. The interval $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ will be called **$\epsilon$-Neighborhood** of $N_{\epsilon}(x)$ is the set of all points that are within a distance of $\epsilon$ from $x$.
Thank you!
Quote of the day:
"*Therefore, O students, study mathematics and do not build without foundations*".
Leonardo di ser Piero da Vinci 
1452-1519

Comment: There are two parts here: 1. the irrationals are dense; 2. the irrationals have empty interior. To prove the latter it is sufficient to show that the rationals are also dense. The choice of a convenient proof for these two statements depends a bit on your choice of definition of the reals. (For example, if the reals are by definition the Cauchy completion of $\mathbb{Q}$, then density of the rationals is immediate.)

Comment: Useful fact: $\partial A$ is the set of points $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $x$ is the limit of a sequence in $A$ as well as the limit of a sequence in $\mathbb R \setminus A$

Comment: Thank you, i'll study your proof.

Answer (score 2):

Let q be any rational number. Then by density theorem every e-neighbourhood of q contains both irrational as well as rational numbers. Therefore q is a boundary point of Irrational numbers. As q was arbitrary, every rational numbers are boundary points of Irrational numbers.

Similarly for irrational numbers.

As R is union of rational and irrational numbers, therefore the boundary point of Irrational numbers are R.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).